# Python regex to match alpha characters only ([A-Za-z] but for Unicode)

Tags: python, regex

I feel silly asking this, the answer must be staring me in the face, but I can't immediately find it either here on with wider googling.

What is the Python regular expression that matches alpha characters (not numerics)? I'm looking for the equivalent of `[A-Za-z]` but for with Unicode support.

Comment: What do you consider an "alpha character"? What if there are combining diacritics?

Comment: As Brad Solomon is saying below, I'm looking for `\w` but without the digits and the underscore. "Alpha character" means whatever current locale or Unicode locale defines as alpha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems like you want is the equivalent of `\w` (which does have Unicode support unless you use the `re.ASCII` flag), but without numerics.  (Or without an underscore, I'm assuming--which is also a part of `\w`.)

What you could do here is to take the equivalent of a "double-negative": exclude `\W` (any character which is not a word character) and exclude `\d` (digits):

```
re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', 'Jalape\xf1o Jal99ape\xf1o')
# ['Jalapeño']
```

Without the word boundaries above, this would capture `['Jalapeño', 'Jal', 'apeño']`.